# Magento Content Block Question

Tags: layout, magento

Noob Question here. I have created and successfully added an additional Page Layout to the existing theme on a client's website.

I then checked what was going on in the content area and found that a file, named grouped.phtml was being called.

**The Problem**:

I want to duplicate that file and call it (for example) grouped2.phtml and add it to my custom page layout, while keeping the first file (grouped.phtml) alone. How do I do this? Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: do you still want to include grouped.phtml in the layout?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm going to try what you added below, and I'll get back to you soon. Thank you Jonathon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy `grouped.phtml` from `base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/` to `grouped2.phtml` in the same directory of your theme.  Edit it as you wish.

Open up `layout/catalog.xml` in your theme.  Find the lines that say

```
   <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra"/>
   </block>
```

Duplicate those lines with your grouped2.phtml

done.

**======EDIT===========**

If you wish to retain the standard grouped.phtml as the default, but use your grouped2.phtml in some specific instances, you can make XML layout changes in the "Custom Layout Update" field on the Design tab of the specific products or categories in the Magento Admin.  In that case, use the following XML:

```
<remove name="product.info.grouped"/>
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.alternative.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped2.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra"/>
   </block>
```

Note that the inserted XML has a different name.

Comment: Let's say that I want to leave grouped.phtml as the default grouped template. I have a custom page layout that I just want the grouped2.phtml to show up on. How do I tie your solution into the new page layout?

Comment: I mean, I've already done what you said, and I'm sure it works, but I just want grouped2.phtml to show up on the new page layout, nowhere else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @willbeeler - see my edited answer, hope this is what you need

Comment: @Jonathan - Would it not be neater to do `<reference name="product.info.grouped"> <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view/type/grouped2.phtml</template> </action> </reference>`?

Comment: Dude you guys rock. Thanks so much. I have to get studying Magento. Again, I can't thank you enough

Comment: @clockworkgeek - yeah, good point.  I guess I was just copy/pasting from my earlier part of the question but that would be a neater solution.